# Object retrieval from JSON using Jquery / JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. I have a JSON file at /path/to/json containing:

   ```
   {"a": {"s": [{"l": "PPP"}]}}
   ```

   I'm using this JQuery expression:

   ```
   $.ajax({
      url: '/path/to/json',
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
          $.each(data.a.s, function(index,element) {
              lines=element.l;           
      })
      }
   });
   ```

   How do I return the value at a.s.l without using $.each()?
2. I have another JSON file containing:

   ```
   {"a": {"s": [
   {
       "l": "PPP",
       "qqq": "aaa"
   },
   {
       "l": "FFF",
       "qqq": "bbb"
   }
   ]}}
   ```

   This is a file. How do I assign the contents of the file to a variable then search within this json for the object who's 'l' attribute is 'PPP' then retrieve that object's 'qqq' value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array index, if you know the index of item to be fetched

To get the first item in the `s` array

```
data.a.s[0].l
```

To get the second item in the `s` array

```
data.a.s[1].l
```

Or use a for loop

```
for(var i= 0; i<data.a.s.length; i++){
    lines = data.a.s[i].l
}
```

Comment: I think this is only answering the second question? How do I assign the contents of the file to a variable?

Comment: @TWolf what do you mean by returning value